# unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ that preserves the decomposability

Tags: group-theory, tensor-products

I have some doubts about the relationship between tensor product and unitary transformations...
Take $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ and think about it as a inner product space with the canonical inner product (we identify $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ with $\mathbb{C^4}$ via Riesz isomorphism). So we are in position of speak about unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$.

Questions:

1. Are there any unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ that preserves decomposability other than the identity? What are their form?
2. Are there any continuous one parameter group of unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ other than $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U(\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}), t\mapsto I$ that preserves decomposability?
3. If I choose a nonzero element of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$, the elements of $U(\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2})$ that preserves the decomposability of such element forms a group?
4. Are there any continuous one parameter group of unitary transformation of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$ other than $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow U(\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}), t\mapsto I$ that preserves decomposability of some specific non zero element of $\mathbb{C^2} \otimes \mathbb{C^2}$?

I've no familiarity with such things (I never studied them), then also any reference about the subject is welcome.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Any isometry of the form $u\otimes v$ with $u,v\in U(2)$ preserves decomposability, and if $u_t,v_t$ are one parameter subgroups of $U(2)$, then $u_t\otimes v_t$ is a one parameter subgroup that preserves decomposability.

Comment: thx a lot :) there are any other?

Comment: There's permutation of factors $x\otimes y\mapsto y\otimes x$, and composites of this and the previous. These might be the only such transformations.

Comment: Do you know if there exists a c.o.p.u.g. not of the previous forms that preserves the decomposability of a nonzero element of the form $u \otimes v$ ?

Comment: A *what*? ${}{}$

Comment: continuous one parameter unitary group

Comment: What does decomposability mean? The ability to be written as a pure tensor $u\otimes v$?

Comment: Yes, we start with an element of the form $u\otimes v$ and of every $t\in \mathbb{R}$ we want that $U(t)(u\otimes v)$ is of the form $u_1\otimes v_1$ for some $u_1,v_1 \in \mathbb{C^2}$, but with U that is not a c.o.p.u.g of the previous form.

Comment: If it helps, we can identify $\Bbb C^2\otimes\Bbb C^2\cong M_2(\Bbb C)$. Pure tensors correspond to singular matrices.